# PHP/SQL - Select data from two tables, from two databases and sort them by time

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to merge data from two tables, from two different databases together and sort the result by time.

I am using PDO in my code, and I can connect to the two databases like this:
`$dbh` *(database1)* and `$Ndbh` *(database2)*

Here is where I get confused. I know I can use the two database selectors mentioned above to get data from each database - but how do I merge the data?

Comment: Unless you can put it into a single query, you will have to manage the join in your PHP - which means pulling in ALL the data and running the checks there (basically YICK!) and finally processing the output.

Comment: are the tables linked in any way? ( ie: have a common key )

Comment: @RamRaider Yes, the type column is an int(), which stores the users ID in both tables.

Comment: Are the two databases in the same rdms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working! This is the code I've used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.title, t1.text, t1.time, t1.userid, t1.type, 
                            t2.id, t2.text, t2.time, t2.timeline_id, t2.type, t2.url
                            FROM database1.table1 t1
                            INNER JOIN database2.table2 t2 on t1.userid = t2.timeline_id;
```

Please note here, that there is a common key value between the two tables - in this case it's `t1.userid` and `t2.timeline_id`

I am using it in PDO like below:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.title, t1.text, t1.time, t1.userid, t1.type, 
                            t2.id, t2.text, t2.time, t2.timeline_id, t2.type, t2.url
                            FROM littlebu_maindb.growl t1
                            INNER JOIN littlebu_social.notifications t2 on t1.userid = t2.timeline_id
                            WHERE t1.userid = :userid AND t2.timeline_id = :userid ;");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
$query1 = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM table1')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$query2 = $Ndbh ->query('SELECT * FROM table2')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$data = array_merge($query1, $query2);

usort($data , function($a, $b) {
    return $a['time'] - $b['time'];
});
```